Find the above layer of UDP when we have FP (Frame Protocol) in pcap file
I have a pcap file with the below layers
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5321, Dst Port: 1038
    Source Port: 5211
    Destination Port: 2038
    Length: 44
    Checksum: 0x0000 [zero-value ignored]
    [Stream index: 17]
    [Timestamps]
        [Time since first frame: 3.231799000 seconds]
        [Time since previous frame: 0.100261000 seconds]
    UDP payload (36 bytes)
FP (PCH)
    [DL setup frame: 19]
    [Release R7 (2006/12)]
    [Channel Type: PCH (0x09)]
    [Division: FDD (0x01)]
    [Direction: Downlink]
    1111 010. = Header CRC: 0x7a [correct]
    .... ...0 = Frame Type: Data (0x0)
    0000 1111 0011 .... = CFN (PCH): 243
    .... ...0 = Paging Indication: no PI-bitmap in payload (0)
    ...0 0001 = TFI: 1
    [Relevant Paging Indications bitmap: 1000000000 (36 bits)]
    TB data for 1 chans (240 bits in 1 tbs)
    Payload CRC: 0x10a4 [correct]
    [Payload CRC Status: Good]
MAC (PCCH)
    [Logical Channel Type: PCCH (0)]
Radio Link Control TM (PCCH)
    Data: 40a3744f292c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Radio Resource Control (RRC) protocol
    PCCH-Message
        message: pagingType1 (0)
            pagingType1
                pagingRecordList: 1 item
                    Item 0
                        PagingRecord: cn-Identity (0)
                            cn-Identity
                                pagingCause: terminatingLowPrioritySignalling (5)
                                cn-DomainIdentity: cs-domain (0)
                                cn-pagedUE-Identity: tmsi-GSM-MAP (1)
                                    tmsi-GSM-MAP: af379496 

I write a C++ Application. How I can find the application layer of UDP? How I can find that the above layer of UDP is FP (Frame Protocol)? Is there any good library to dissect FP/MAC/RLC/RRC layer in C++?
